# 1+n issue with entities having 1-1 association

Tags: hibernate, jpa, domain-driven-design

In my business domain two entities `Request` and `Action` are in one to one association as under: [image]

I am persisting them through hibernate. Problem is, if I save them in two tables I will have to face 1+n problem. If I save them in one table (by inheriting them from same super class) hibernate uses discriminator so that they end up in two different rows of the table that means same 1+n issue.
Is it possible that I could save associated instances of these two entities in different columns of same row of a table having same Id? Or some better idea to deal with this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, two instances should not be used to represent the same row, as what happens when you go to delete one of the entities?  Why not just use one entity and one embeddable?  Assuming that Action cannot exist without the Request, it would be the embeddable and exist in the Request table.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered lazy-fetching Action. This will avoid fetching Action until you actually really need it. for e.g.
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)

Comment: Yes, in some situations it makes life better but fails in queries like "get all requests having no action". Since I have many pairs of such entities so I am trying to find most efficient way

Answer (score 0):

I prefer one-to-one solution if Request and Action are both **Entity**.  I use criteria query and specify fetch mode to join to avoid n+1 problem.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Request .class);
c.setFetchMode("action", FetchMode.JOIN)
return c.list();
```

However, this is a little bit cumbersome that you have to develop many ad-hoc query method if your Request associates with more than one **Entity**.

```
public interface RequestRepository {
      List<Request> findWithAction(Criteria criteria);

      List<Request> findWithAnotherEntity(Criteria criteria);
}
```

I use @Embeded if Action is just a **ValueObject**, therefore they could be stored in one table.